# How to CSS Img Border on Hover without Shifting Image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a border around an image appear with mouse hover. The following does what I'm looking for, but it shifts the image when the border appears. How can this same effect be made with moving the image?

Here's a jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/8gA6z/

```
.screenshots {
    float: left;
    width: 155px;
}
.screenshots img:hover{
    border: 5px solid #06C;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give transparent border and change border-color on hover

```
.screenshots img {
    border:5px solid transparent;
}
.screenshots img:hover {
    border-color:#06C;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/8gA6z/3/)

Answer (score 3):

You could give it a border that's transparent and the same width when not being hovered:

```
.screenshots img {
    border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8gA6z/2/)**